# Alfresco share:How to popup edit-metadata after upload

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am currently using alfresco community Edition 4.0d.
I have added a new content model in alfresco share.
in this one of my requirement is either before or after uploading the document the Edit properites pop up form should be appear..
Means if i click on upload the docuemnt and upload the document is succesfully done ,then edit properties form should be pop up. What should i do for this.

I do't wont to use addons.

Please reply..
.

Comment: Alfresco Community 4.0d is a little old now, you might want to upgrade to a newer one for new features + bug fixes!

Answer (score 1):

you'll have to have to tweak Share's JavaScript components:

add a custom flag to "metadataRefresh" event object that is fired in x-upload.js
tweak handling of "metadataRefresh" event in documentlist.js to call the relevant action, e.g. onActionDetails()

Comment: I can not understand more.Can u just elobrate some more.Or give some code so i can understand that.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about your question, but I am working on a project somewhat similar to yours. What I did was, I looked to see how the upload button works then I interjected my code in the upload button js code to bring up my dialog before the upload brings up its own dialog.
Please let me know if this helps.